# Is there a way to automate the defining of a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there is a way to automate the defining of a function. For instance I want  a set of functions like:

```
def add1:
    list.append(x)
def add2:
    list.append(y)
def add3:
    list2.append(x)
...
```

The problem is that I have to define lots of these, 232 to be exact. Is there a faster way to do this? Also, I use Python 3.2.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you can use lambda functions if it is doing something in a pattern.

Comment: The better question is, why do you think you need 232 functions that are almost the same

Comment: Why do you want to define 232 functions? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Can you show us the code of `add1` and explain how it is different from `add2`, `add3`, ... ?

Comment: What is a lambda function? I need these to be used in a tkinter checkbox widget. These functions are similar but contain some variations.

Comment: What about using a closure to "generate" the needed functions?

Comment: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `exec`

example:

```
def your_common_function(i, txt):
   # here you may decide what to do with arguments according to "i" value
   if i == 1:
      print(txt)
   else:
      print(txt+'s')

for i in range(1, 233):
    exec("def add%d(txt):\n\tyour_common_function(%d, txt)" % (i, i))

add1("hello world")  # prints "hello world"
add167("hello world")  # prints "hello worlds"
```

**EDIT** I changed my code to allow you to define different behaviours according to the "function number"